# why my omega sign comes up as '\xce\xa9'? in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a_list.extend(['four','Ω'])
a_list

['a', 2.0, 3, True, 'four', '\xce\xa9']
```

why does it shows me xce\xa9? and not the sign omega?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: The OMEGA Symbol is a Unicode Character.  It is represented as two Bytes in an ASCII STRING.  For UTF-8 encoding those bytes are 0xCE & 0xA9.  Perhaps you want to display the correct character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python