# Pythonic way to encode list items nested in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, encoding

On Console:

```
>>> print {"key": ["äüö"]}
{'key': ['\xc3\xa4\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6']}
```

How can I easily let python print something like this:

```
>>> print {"key": ["äüö"]}
{'key': ['äüö']}
```

I don't like to print unicode characters like in [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)
 I like to have an easy way to print the content of a dictionary.

Comment: Switch to python3

Comment: You should use unicode string : `u"äüö"` (instead of bytes string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)

Comment: @Mel: This is not really a duplicate. Here, the OP wants to print the content of a dictionary. For that, Python use the `repr()` function, so he got escaped characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print a collection with Python 2, for instance a `dict` or a `list`, Python uses the `repr()` function to print the items of the collections.

In the case of a string (unicode string) you get escaped characters…

To do what you want, using Python 2, you need to print the dictionary yourself, like this:

```
>>> d = {"key": [u"äüö"]}
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     print(u"{k}: [{v}]".format(k=k, v=u", ".join(u"'{0}'".format(i) for i in v)))
```

You get:

```
key: ['äüö']
```

Comment: Ok, nice solution. But what if the collection is more complex. E.g more nested dictionaries with nested lists? So I have to write a more complex parser.