# lxml in Python: Scraping shows only English characters (others are garbled)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, lxml.html

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from lxml.etree import HTML
title_req = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VK3QWm7jvZs")
title_main = HTML(title_req.content)
title = title_main.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")[0]
print(title)
>> Halsey - Without Me - Ù\x85ØªØ±Ø¬Ù\x85Ø© Ø¹Ø±Ø¨Ù\x8a
```

I want it to be like this:

```
>> Halsey - Without Me - مترجمة عربي
```

I tried to add UTF-8 encoding but its not working

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)

Comment: no its not same problem, thx

Comment: A question can be marked as duplicate if the *solution* is the same, even if the problem description is different. If one of the solutions on the other question solves the problem, the question is considered a duplicate.

Comment: i tried the solutions from the topic u say possible duplicate but it isn't working because the problem is from **lxml** not utf-8

Comment: what console do you use. cmd, bash, powershell?

Comment: Try writing the file by `with open('urls.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:f.write(title)`

Comment: visual studio code but the problem apears when i save the string to file & when i print it

Comment: visual studio code doesn't have console. They use the one with the system. I guess it's console problem.

Comment: when i use your code is save this in the urls.txt:       Halsey - Without Me - ÙØªØ±Ø¬ÙØ© Ø¹Ø±Ø¨Ù

Comment: I checked it on linux and same problem. Looks like you have real issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but this line is creating problem.

```
title_main = HTML(title_req.content)
```

change it to

```
title_main = HTML(title_req.text)
```

I will try to know why.

Comment: On Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10, I get the following error message: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 22-27: character maps to <undefined>". What specific version of Python 3 are you using?

Comment: r.text is the content of the response in unicode, and r.content is the content of the response in bytes.

Comment: python 3.6.3 64-bit visual studio code and its **WORKED**