# How to read accented characters from a string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get characters from string "test?àâ". My output contains "�" in place of accented chracters. My python code is given below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
s = 'test?àâ'

for c in s:
    print c
```

Output :

```
t
e
s
t
?
�
�
�
�
```

Comment: Define it as `s = u'test?àâ'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43989185/58129

Comment: You really should consider switching to Python 3, were this sort of thing works more intuitively. Perhaps see also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @tripleee I need to run this code on redshift and I think redshift doesn't support python 3 till now.