# I have to export a special character to a file for a transcribing program

Tags: shortcut, numpad

I have a French special character 'œ' I want to export into the template of a transcribing program file. When I write it plainly in the python code, then the transcriber doesn't recognize that character.
Within the transcriber itself, though I use a numpad command to make this character, namely alt+156. I was wondering if there is a way to simulate that input within a python code.
Any help welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.