# How to send accented characters with diacritics in HTTP request-payload?

Tags: python, unicode, httprequest, diacritics

I am requiring to send special characters like accented characters with diacritics, e.g. [o-acute `ó`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93), via API

This is my test code

```
import string
import http.client
import datetime
import json

def apiSendFarmacia(idatencion,articulo,deviceid):
    ##API PAYLOAD
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("apimocha.com")
    payload = json.dumps({
      "idatencion": idatencion,
      "articulo": articulo,
      "timestamp": str(now),
      "deviceId": deviceid
      
    }).encode("utf-8")
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    conn.request("POST"
                ,"/xxxx/api2"#"/my/api/path" #"/alexa"
                , payload
                , headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    httpcode = res.status
    data = res.read()
    return httpcode#, data.decode("utf-8")
    ##API PAYLOAD
```

when executing the function with some special characters

```
apiSendFarmacia(2222,"solución",2222)
```

the mock API will receive following JSON payload with `\u00f3` instead of `ó`:

```json
{
      "idatencion": 2222,
      "articulo": "soluci\u00f3n",
      "timestamp": "2022-12-07 14:52:24.878976",
      "deviceId": 2222
}
```

I was expecting the special character with its accent-mark `ó` to show in the mock API.

Comment: And that's exactly what it should do.  Doesn't that work?  Remember, that string does not actually contain a backslash or a 0.  Python just shows it to you like that.

Comment: The resulting JSON is correct. Did you expect anything else?

Comment: Name the special-characters in your question, e.g. the [o-acute `ó`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93) which gets represented as Unicode  `\u00f3` in your resulting string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you print it, it will appear as the special character:

```
>>> print('soluci\u00f3n')
solución
```

`u00f3` denotes the hexadecimal representation for [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE' (U+00F3)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm).

The `\` is an escape-signal that tells the interpreter that the subsequent character(s) has to be treated as special character. For example `\n` is interpreted as newline, `\t` as tab and `\u00f3` as Unicode character `ó`.

Comment: See also [How to print Unicode character in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python) or [Unicode HOWTO — Python 3.11.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Helpful explanation of escaping-concept and Unicode character representation. Hope you don't mind my improving edit. Feel free to add my "See also" links so I can remove my comment.