# How do I define strings read from a file as Unicode?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)

I want to strip a input string from a file from all special characters, except for actual letters (even Cyrillic letters shouldn't be stripped). The solution I found manually declares the string as unicode and the pattern with the `re.UNICODE` flag so actual letters from different languages are detected.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
pattern = re.compile("[^\w\d]",re.UNICODE)
n_uni = 'ähm whatßs äüöp ×äØü'
uni = u'ähm whatßs äüöp ×äØü'
words = pattern.split(n_uni) #doesn't work
u_words = pattern.split(uni) #works
```

So if I write the string directly in the source and manually define it as Unicode it gives me the desired output while the non-Unicode string gives me just garbage:

```
"ähm whatßs äüöp äØü" -> unicode
"hm what s ü p ü" -> non-unicode even with some invalid characters
```

My question is now how do I define the input from a file as Unicode?

Comment: Seriously. Searching for "python read unicode file" on Google gives you the relevant documentation as the first hit. And the duplicate StackOverflow question as hit #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is now how do I define the input from a file as unicode?

Straight from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

Comment: Works now was a problem with my setup.