# python storing unicode to mysql

Tags: python, unicode

having problem to store unicode to database. for your information 你 = you..

```
>> a='你'
>>a <\br>
'\xc4\xe3'
```

the problem is

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import MySQLdb
 db = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="root",db="mydata", charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)

 cursor = db.cursor()

  insert = "insert into testing (english,chinese,frequency) values(%s,%s,1) on duplicate KEY UPDATE frequency=frequency+1;"
  a='你'
 data=('you',a)
 try:
    cursor.execute(insert,data) 
 except:
    print "error"

 db.commit()
```

which return me an error, but when i change to this

```
data=('you','你')
```

it works....

can anyone help me?? i need to use "data=('you',a)" because later i will import chinese chracter file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try telling python to treat the string as unicode, like this: `a= u'你'`

If you're not using an interactive prompt, you can accomplish this via the `unicode` function. An example of one way to load data would be:

```
fname = 'somefile.txt'
with open(fname,'r') as f
    unicode_data = unicode(f.read())
```

If this doesn't work, you should be able to fine more details in the python docs: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html and also you may find this SO answer helpful: [Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)

Comment: thank a lot ...how about i read the file and store as u'chinese  _character'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: for an example, a="你好" then "a" will be '\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3' <br/> how do i make it to u'\xc4\xe3\xba\xc3'

Comment: try using the `unicode()` function. Edited my response to assume you are loading data from an external file.

Comment: i think here the error "chi = unicode(f.read())"<br/> error message UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a pro at working with unicode. I hope this other SO response helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python