# Python: How to fix an [errno 2] when trying to open a text file?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to learn Python in my free time, and my textbook is not covering anything about my error, so I must've messed up badly somewhere. When I try to open and read a text file through notepad (on Windows) with my code, it produces the error. My code is:

```
def getText():
    infile = open("C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/lib/book.txt" , "r")
    allText = infile.read()
    return allText
```

If it's necessary, here is the rest of my code so far:

```
def inspectWord(theWord,wList,fList):
    tempWord = theWord.rstrip("\"\'.,`;:-!")
    tempWord = tempWord.lstrip("\"\'.,`;:-!")
    tempWord = tempWord.lower()
    if tempWord in wList:
        tIndex = wList.index(tempWord)
        fList[tIndex]+=1
    else:
        wList.append(tempWord)
        fList.append(1)

def main():
     myText = getText()
     print(myText)

main()
```

I'd greatly appreciate any advice, etc.; I cannot find any help for this. Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: Err No. 2 means python can’t find the file.  Are you sure the path to the file is correct?

Comment: You presumably have the wrong file path or the file does not exist.

Comment: I looked at the text file's properties and found it because I had named it "book.txt" and it was already a .txt file, file was apparently "book.txt.txt". I just took out one of the .txts, but now it's giving me an error in the traceback saying:         "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 13261: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

To open a unicode file, you can do the following

```
import codecs

def getText():
    with codecs.open("C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/lib/book.txt" , "r", encoding='utf8') as infile:
        allText = infile.read()
    return allText
```

See also:  [Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to use relative path, not absolute path. It is simpler and will make your life easier especially now that you just started to learn Python. If you know how to deal with commandline, run a new commandline and move to the directory where your source code is located. Make a new text file there and now you can do something like

```
 f = open("myfile.txt")
```

Your error indicates that there is something wrong with path you passed to builtin function **open**. Try this in an interactive mode,

```
>> import os
>> os.path.exists("C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/lib/book.txt")
```

If this returns False, there is nothing wrong with your **getText** fuction. Just pass a correct path to **open** function.