# Handling a dictionary that has keys that are unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode

I have a dictionary that each key is unicode and I'm using the following code to insert JSON file into a dictionary.

```
def readDictFromFile(filename):
    my_file = Path(filename)
    if my_file.is_file():
        return json.load(codecs.open(filename,encoding='utf-8'))
    return {}
```

But when I try to check if a string is in the dictionary, it does not work:

```
if title in dict:
    continue
```

The reason is that the dict contains keys that look like: `u'\u05d5`. I say that I need to use `repr` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)) but is there a way to do it with the same syntax without looping for each key in the dict?

Comment: maybe you need raw strings? please show a [mcve]

Comment: Is the "\u..." really contained in the string (backslash character, then "u" character,...) or is it just shown as representation, e. g. by "repr()" or a Python shell?

Comment: @MichaelButscher when I print the dict (`print(dict)`) it prints `u'\u05d4`