# Adding word starting with kurdish characters to a new file in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I tried this code with english characters works with no problem but i when i want to test it with kurdish characters it will not add anything to new file
here is my ckb.txt:

```
چ
چۆنی
باشی
سوپاس
ئاسمان
یاسا
دەنگ
```

ckbnew.txt is empty textfile which i want to add text from ckb.txt

This is my code:

```
import unicodedata

f = open('ckb.txt', 'r')
d = open('ckbnew.txt', 'w')
g = f.readlines()
for line in g:
    if line.startswith('\u0686') :
        d.write(line)
    print(line)
```

Comment: The file is in unicode, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you, adding encoding='utf-8' solved the problem.